# copy datetime value from csv into excel using macro

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to open a list of csv file and copy the data into different spreadsheets of a excel file.
My script is as follows

```
Sub importcsv()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strCSV As String
    strFile = "D:\15049"
    strCSV = "A4260512_ECRec.csv"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFile & "\" & strCSV
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("test 150302.xlsm").Sheets("test2").Range("A1")
    Workbooks(strCSV).Close
End Sub
```

The problem I have is in my csv file there is one colume of date time data (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm), when copying those to excel, some are copied in the right order, some are not. For example, 31/3/1990 is copied exactly but 1/4/1990 is copied as 4/1/1990. In my region setting, date format is set as d/mm/yyyy.

Anyone has any idea? Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Is it possible that the destination file is just displaying a different format of the same date?

Comment: In the destination file, 31/3/1990 appears as general format and 4/1/1990 appears as date format. When I changed date format to dd/mm/yyyy, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the number format for the area to be copies and to be pasted?

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").NumberFormat = "YYYY/MM/DD"
```

range and rows

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A17").NumberFormat = ""
Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just tried it and it still didn't work. I think excel still read '1/4/1990' as mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Yes, it only happens when the date in the csv file is in range 1 to 12. Eg. in my csv file  
24/07/2008 347
25/07/2008 362
26/07/2008 364
27/07/2008 367
28/07/2008 364
29/07/2008 360
30/07/2008 354
31/07/2008 337
01/08/2008 337
02/08/2008 333
03/08/2008 336
04/08/2008 343 And in my destination file: 23/07/2008 
24/07/2008 347
25/07/2008 362
26/07/2008 364
27/07/2008 367
28/07/2008 364
29/07/2008 360
30/07/2008 354
31/07/2008 337
08/01/2008 337
08/02/2008 333
08/03/2008 336
08/04/2008 343

Comment: If you only need to do this once, I guess you can go around it by using if statement. Test the DD value if it is equal or less than 12, use dd/mm/yyyy as number format. OR try with paste special? (i.e. Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the column as being in DMY format, at the time you open the file.  You can do this in one of two ways

1. Add a connection to a QueryTable -- this done manually would be using the Data Ribbon / Get External Data tab /From Text
2. Change the file suffix to `.txt` and then use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method.

Both of the above provide options to specify that the date column format is DMY.